# SQL command to tally results over multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following SQL table titled 'calls' which is a complete list of calls from John's phone bill:

```
Sample Data Set for a Call log:
from, to, length (min)
John, Jill, 15
John, Jill, 7
Jill, John, 4
John, Jill, 6
John, Jill, 9
```

I have figured out that the following query:

```
SELECT calls.from, calls.to, COUNT(1) AS call_count
FROM `mydb.calls` AS calls
WHERE calls.from = "John" OR calls.to = "John"
GROUP BY calls.from, calls.to
ORDER by call_count DESC
```

Gives me the following result:

```
row, from, to, call_count
1, John, Jill, 4
2, Jill, John, 1
```

What I really want and what I can't figure out is how to tally the total results for both inbound and outbound calls from John's perspective. I want to essentially display the following:

```
row, who, inbound, outbound, total
1, Jill, 1, 4, 5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic for the grouping key:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN c.from = 'John' THEN c.to ELSE c.from END) as who, 
       COUNT(*) AS call_count
FROM `mydb.calls` c
WHERE 'John' in (c.from, c.to)
GROUP BY who
ORDER by call_count DESC;

SELECT (CASE WHEN c.from = 'John' THEN c.to ELSE c.from END) as who, 
       COUNT(*) AS call_count,
       SUM(c.from = 'John') as inbound,
       SUM(c.to = 'John') as outbound
FROM `mydb.calls` c
WHERE 'John' in (c.from, c.to)
GROUP BY who
ORDER by call_count DESC
```

Comment: That was quick! Going to try.

Comment: Definitely seems to work! Thank you! How would one go about adding two additional columns? Namely the inbound and outbound column?

Comment: Thank you very much! Are you a freelancer by chance?

Comment: FYI - When running from BQ I had to use SUM(CAST(c.from = 'John' AS INT64)) as inbound

Comment: @AlwaysLearning . . . Your question is tagged MySQL and this code will work in MySQL.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. You've been of great help. Thank you so much!